# Some problems about live data

Tags: checkbox, android-livedata

In sign up fragment,  I have **term condition part**. When you click this text, bottom sheets opens. I  click the button that end of the page(Accept Button). I want checkbox in sign up should be clicked.

**Repository**

```
  var resultOk = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
  fun checkResult(){
    resultOk.value = true
}
```

**Sign Up View Model**

```
`
private var _resultOk = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val resultOk: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _resultOk

 init {
    _resultOk = firebaseRepo.resultOk
}
```

**Sign Up Fragment**

```
      viewModel.resultOk.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        binding.cbTermsAndCondition.isChecked = it
    })
```

**BottomSheetView Model**

```
  init {
    checkResult()
}

fun checkResult() {
    fireBaseRepository.checkResult()
}
```

**BottomSheet Fragment**

```
     binding.btnTermAccept.setOnClickListener {
        //Constant.result.value = true
        //viewModel.resultOk.value
        viewModel.checkResult()
        dismiss()
    }
```

Why checkbox is not clicked, when I click "accept button" end of the bottomsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. There are 2 way to solve this problem.

**1)** `var result =MutableLiveData(false)` you should do it as Singleton and then observe it.

**2)** You can use shared viewModel [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0)